# Kafka S3 source connector: How to avoid data loss when a node is down?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I have a system that runs on 3 AWS nodes and uses Kafka S3 source connector for reading data from an S3 bucket. I am streaming data events to the S3 buckets, do some processing on these events and write the processed data back to S3 bucket.
In order to test the system durability, I am deliberately stopping one of the nodes for a couple of minutes while the data is being streamed, and then bring it back up.
I sporadically experience data loss of a single event.
I tried to find a pattern in this data loss by stopping the node that runs specific broker/connector replica, the node that runs the my data processing module, the node that runs the broker that is the leader of specific topics (e.g. __consumer_offsets). Unfortunately, none of my attempts brought me to a situation where I can reproduce this issue 100% of the times (rather than experience it sporadically).

I get the following errors in the S3 connector log (file-00036.in is the data event that is lost in this case):

> WARN Failed to load committed offset for object file
> s3://metro-bucket-221hsbomum/in/file-00036.in. Previous offset will be
> ignored. Error: Failed to fetch offsets.
> (io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.source.DefaultFileRecordsPollingConsumer)
> [task-thread-s1-ilcera-0] ERROR Failed to get object metadata from
> Amazon S3. Error occurred while making the request or handling the
> response for s3://metro-bucket-221hsbomum/in/file-00036.in: {}
> (io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.AmazonS3Storage)
> [task-thread-s1-ilcera-0]

Any idea why this problem occurs and how to avoid it?
Alternatively, suggestions for possible things I can try in order to get to a situation in which I can consistently reproduce this issue can be very helpful too.

Comment: could you share offsets.retention.minutes and  auto.offset.reset property values.

Comment: Hi @kus,
offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
auto.offset.reset = earliest

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer,
I apologize but I've made a mistake. In the post description I meant to write S3 source connector (rather than sink connector). Obviously my problem occurs when reading from the S3 bucket. Depending on the data format, this is the connector I am using: "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.fs.reader.AmazonS3RowFileInputReader/AmazonS3BytesArrayInputReader/AmazonS3RowFileInputReader" - [link](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/archives/v2.3.x/developer-guide/file-readers/)

Comment: I don't have experience with this connector... Have you searched/created an issue here yet? https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse/issues

Comment: i think problem statement is not clear. As per analysis this issue is not in kafka.   The probable issue is in "kafka-connect-file-pulse" package or maybe problem need to be re-define. Above log indicates  issue occurred while fetching the S3 object. For example: s3://metro-bucket-221hsbomum/in/file-00036.in , this file might have been processed by different thread.  This is irrelevant if kafka broker is down, focus should be around application server or threading implementation.